# Always get an Error 404 when i try to get swagger.json

Tags: java, rest, swagger, resteasy, seam

My problem is that, i have an RESTEasy api with seam in java, a maven project, this works correctly but when im trying to document this api with swagger, the swagger.json file is never founded. I dont know what the problem is.

```
pom.xml:
```

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-seam-resteasy</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependencia swagger -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-jaxrs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-models -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.20</version>
    </dependency>
```

web.xml:

```
<!-- Swagger -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SwaggerConfigurationServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>SwaggerConfigurationServlet</display-name>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-class>packageOfSwaggerConfiguration.SwaggerConfigurationServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>`
```

SwaggerConfigurationServlet:

```
@ApplicationPath("v3")

public class SwaggerConfigurationServlet extends Application {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -9026370104891567770L;

public void Init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
    BeanConfig beanConfig=new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[] {"http"});
    beanConfig.setBasePath("http://localhost:8080/NameOfProyect/seam/resource/rest");
    beanConfig.setTitle("Swagger");
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("PackageOfApi");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
    beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);
}
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();


    // here I add my REST WSs
    s.add(ApiListingResource.class);
    s.add(SwaggerSerializers.class);


    return s;
}

index.html:



$(function () {

  var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/);
  if (url && url.length > 1) {
    url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
  } else {
    url = "http://localhost:8080/NameOfProyect/seam/resource/rest/swagger.json";
  }
```

I expect that the swagger.json file is in http://localhost:8080/NameOfProyect/seam/resource/rest/swagger.json or 
http://localhost:8080/NameOfProyect/seam/resource/rest/v3/swagger.json

but is never founded.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your application path is wrong. Should you check it.